Conffessing sin still can be punishable?
Is confessing your sins punishable?
I want to ask you this because I rotted my own mind by watching trans porn for years. Then as I got closer to Islam, I started to feel sad, and I started confessing it to my family and friends. My heart was relieved because I confessed my sins and I started going to the doctor to relieve my distress. I still watch porn, but it convinces me more and more to get better.
Now what I want to ask is. If you commit criminal sins like adultery and homosexuality, but then you repent and confess, are you still punished according to Islam?
I know that with 4 witnesses you can kill a homosexual. But what if a gay person repents and confesses to an imam?
In my opinion, if he admits a sin and confesses it to someone, can he still be punished?
If he doesn't tell anyone, he won't be punished, but I believe that confession plays an important role in healing.

Salam and welcome to ISlamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help]. Note that the confession of the guilty person is a reason for receiving a punishment. However, if you were not a Muslim at the time you committed these acts then your old sins are wiped away.
